# UK visa application: What visa type do I need to select?

Tags: visas, uk

I work in the Amsterdam office of a tech company. My company is asking us to visit the Uk office for a week. What visa type do I need to select?

[image]

Comment: What is your citizenship? You may not need a visa to make a business trip to the UK https://www.gov.uk/visit-uk-business-trip

Comment: What will you be doing while at the office?
Also, note that all of these will result in a "visit" class visa. If you wanted to apply for a different type of visa (eg work, education) then you would need to have gone on a different form anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I will be doing normal work there. My citizenship is pakistani and I have need a visa to visit

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a clear business visit.

According to appendix 3 of the [visitor rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules):

> **Business – general activities**
>
> 5 A visitor may:
>           (a) attend meetings, conferences, seminars, interviews;
>           (b) give a one-off or short series of talks and speeches provided these are not organised as commercial events and will not make a profit for the organiser;
>           (c) negotiate and sign deals and contracts;
>           (d) attend trade fairs, for promotional work only, provided the visitor is not directly selling;
>           (e) carry out site visits and inspections;
>           (f) gather information for their employment overseas;
>           (g) be briefed on the requirements of a UK based customer, provided any work for the customer is done outside of the UK.
>
> **Business – corporate***
>
> Intra-corporate activities
>
> 6 An employee of an overseas based company may:
>           (a) advise and consult;
>           (b) trouble-shoot;
>           (c) provide training;
>           (d) share skills and knowledge; on a specific internal project with UK employees of the same corporate group, provided no work is carried out directly with clients.
>
> 7 An internal auditor may carry out regulatory or financial audits at a UK branch of the same group of companies as the visitor’s employer overseas.

If you do work that do not fall under this or one of the other exceptions in appendix 3, you will need a different kind of visa that may be hard to get. In that case your company should be paying someone for proper legal guidance.

Comment: Depends what will be taking place during the visit. If they will be doing their normal work, it would be none of the above, and a work visa would be required.

Comment: So, will the visa get rejected if we tell them we will be doing our normal work?

Comment: @x131: I'm assuming that the company will not send the OP simply for doing "normal work" that they could as well have done at home. I have added a quote and link to more specific rules on what a business visitor is allowed to do.